# How can I print a specific occurrence of a range pattern?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to extract several data fields out of somewhat peculiarly formatted strings.

Each string has a format similar to the following (spaces added for emphasis):

```
1 abcd 2 1 efg 2 hij 3 klmnopqrs 5 tuv 6 5 wxyzäüö 6
```

where each number represents another field delimiter. This is what I am trying to extract:

```
  abcd           hij   klmnopqrs 5 tuv 6   wxyz
```

The `1..2` and `5..6` patterns occur only once in some cases. `1..2` ranges only appear before `3`. `5..6` ranges only appear after `3`.

So far I have been successful in extracting `abcd` and `hij` with the following code:

- `abcd`:

  ```
  echo "$STRING" | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="2"}{gsub(/.*1/,"");print;exit}'
  ```
- `hij`:

  ```
  echo "$STRING" | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="3"}{gsub(/.*2/,"");print;exit}'
  ```

Now I am looking for a way to grab `wxyz` and `klmnopqrs`.

- `wxyz` are the **first four** characters in the **last** `5..6` range pattern of the string
- `klmnopqrs` is the field delimited by the **first** occurrence of `3` and the **last** occurrence of `5`

After searching the web for an hour I am now at wit's end. I'd appreciate any help in finding a way to extract these range patterns.

**Edit**: Here's a few input samples that are closer to the real deal:

```
(test)(te st) tesst. test test test test [teest] [teseeet]
(teeeest)(te st) tst. tet test [teseet]
(tst) tst. tet test [tseeet]
```

This is what I would like to extract in each case:

```
 test         tesst  test test test test [teest] tese
 teeeest         tst  tet test tese
 tst  tst  tet test  tsee
```

The field delimiters are special characters, as you an see. Both the width of the strings and the number of `1..2` and `5..6` ranges (here `(..)` and `[..]`) are variable.

Comment: how about an _actual_ sample of the input? Are the delimiters _actually_ numbers, or some other characters? Are these fixed-width lines?

Comment: @awk_FTW Thanks for the pointers. I updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "1 abcd 2 1 efg 2 hij 3 klmnopqrs 5 tuv 6 5 wxyzäüö 6" | 
perl -lne '
    @out = ();
    /1 (.+?) 2/                 and push @out, $1;
    /.+2 \K(.+?) 3 (.+?)(?= 5)/ and push @out, $1, $2;
    /(5.+?6)/                   and push @out, $1;
    /.+5 (....)/                and push @out, $1;
    print join " ", @out
'
```

```
abcd hij klmnopqrs 5 tuv 6 wxyz
```

---

We need to take care to escape the regex special chars properly:

```
perl -lne '
    @out = ();
    /\((.+?)\)/                 and push @out, $1;
    /.+\) \K(.+?)\.(.+)(?= \[)/ and push @out, $1, $2;
    /.+\[(....)/                and push @out, $1;
    print join " ", @out
' <<END
(test)(te st) tesst. test test test test [teest] [teseeet]
(teeeest)(te st) tst. tet test [teseet]
(tst) tst. tet test [tseeet]
END
```

```
test tesst  test test test test [teest] tese
teeeest tst  tet test tese
tst tst  tet test tsee
```

Your desired output:

```
 test         tesst  test test test test [teest] tese
 teeeest         tst  tet test tese
 tst  tst  tet test  tsee
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer works perfectly for the example I provided. Unfortunately I think that I abstracted my example a bit too much. The real input is delimited by special characters. When I replace the numbers in your script with the (escaped) delimiters [it outputs the wrong fields](http://pastebin.com/Px6rdYPR). Is there any chance you could take another look at my edited question?

Comment: @Glutanimate that's why you should provide _an actual sample_ of the input. If it contains sensitive information, just change _the information_ not the format and such. A line of _test test test_ is not very helpful either though.

Comment: @ Glenn: Thank you. This is absolutely brilliant! @awk_FTW: You're right and I'll make sure to do it like that from now on.